# How to run JavaScript code represented by a string?

Tags: javascript

Through AJAX I receive random string (built at **RUNTIME** on the server) that contain some JavaScript code like:

```
Plugins.add('test', function()
 { 
        return
            {
                html: '<div>test</div>',//EDITED
                width: 200
            }
 });//EDITED
```

In the client I want to be able to execute this code. I tried using `eval` function like this

```
eval("(" + str + ")");
```

but I get error. I removed all "**\r\n**" and removed the last "**;**"(semicolon) and after that `eval` function succeeded. But, If I add some comment to the code above, `eval` fails.

How I can run the code from the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Function(str)()
```

or for JSON:

```
new Function('return ' + str)();
```

If it happens to fit your needs any better than eval.  It's still evil like eval.

Comment: Why it is evil? The script is executed in the Client!

Comment: Because most of the time you don't have control over eval()'d code.  If that's not the case (if YOU are generating the code), it's fine.  If it's coming from ANYWHERE else you run risks of exposing yourself to any form of an XSS attack that may be applicable on your site.

Comment: thank you. I generate the code, so I control it. Why **Function** is better than **eval**? Will function evaluate the code even that it contains NEWLINEs?

Comment: no, it's the same. The problem is that usually the reason for any server-generated code is to pass any *data* to the client (or why do you need it server-generated at all otherwise?). If you don't do **all** necessary escaping, checking etc. a malicious user may misuse your eval() statement to inject code and he can do whatever is possible with JavaScript. Just google for "evil eval" and you'll find lots of info.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove those parenthesis:

```
eval(str);
```

asssuming that you made a typo in your question and your server is sending the missing end parenthesis and comma within the object:

```
Plugins.add('test', function()
 { 
        return {
                html: '<div>test</div>',  // <-- comma was missing
                width: 200
        };
 }
);   // <-- was missing
```

Note that `eval()` is considered "evil" as it is very dangerous.

Comment: Indeed, better to use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: The comma and missing parenthesis are NOT the problem(Updated the post). I just missed them in the post. I tried **eval** with AND without parenthesis, this is not working.

Comment: move the `{` to the same line as the `return` and it will work. I've updated my solution accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma in your object literal. `Return` on its own line will simply drop out of the function. I assume you want to return the object. You need to specify the return value on the same line.

```
Plugins.add('test', function() { 
   var ret =   {
                html: '<div>test</div>',
                width: 200,
            }     
   return ret

 };
```

Comment: `return {` followed by a line-break and the rest of the object works too.

Comment: right, but you have some typos in your code (one excess comma, two semicolons missing and the end parenthesis missing). :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could return your string with a content type of `"text/javascript"` or `"application/x-javascript"` - the return value will be executed as JavaScript as soon as it is returned.